# Convert DateTime to AM/PM and restrict to 12 hours format in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

I want to convert and restrict the DateTime to 12 hours format.
Right now the output is: 02-01-2022 18:30 PM
But I want to convert into: 02/01/2022 06:30 PM +00:00.

Comment: A DateTime does not have a format, it only represents a point in time.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")`
Add tt at last for AM/PM

Comment: But it is not restricting to 12 hours format and also at the end it is not showing +00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
string CustomDateFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt +00:00");
```

or

```
string CustomDateFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt") + "+00:00";
```

where hh is for 12 hours format and tt for AM/PM as in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Instead of hard code "+00:00". We can use 'zzz' it is used for time zone designator.